# Model specified for CakePHP Views

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, view, controller

Hey all, have a slight problem here. In CakePHP I have a controller that uses several models. When creating a form in a view, the view will always name my UI elements based on what the first model is when I specify `$uses = array('Model')` so for instance if my User model is the first in my array then my UI elements will receive `id="User(fieldname)"` and `name="data['User'][fieldname]"`

Anybody know how I switch the models my views are using so I can name them properly according to the data I am manipulating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a form use the full dot notation:

```
echo $this->Form->create('ModelName');
echo $this->Form->text('ModelName.field_name');
echo $this->Form->input('ModelName.field_name');
```